# Running several hierarchical linear regressions, all have the same Mahalanobis Distance. Is this weird?

Tags: regression, spss, mahalanobis

As the title says I've run several hierarchical linear regressions on SPSS and I've found that all 6 of them have the same Mahalanobis Distance. I'm wondering if this is a normal thing to happen or might indicate that I've done something wrong?

So, literally, every single case/participant has an identical Mahalanobis Distance in all 6 of the regressions.  Interestingly though each case has a different cook's distance in each of different regression.

My regressions all have the same predictor variables (level 1: age, gender, level 2: emotion regulation strategies) but different criterion variables (different personality traits) so I'm not sure if that could be the reason?

Thanks,
L

Comment: It's hard to speculate about six hierarchical models with data. Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Hi thanks, for getting back to me. I'd have to check with my supervisors as I, unfortunately, don't think our ethics lets us share the raw data, even after it has been anonymised. Does this sound odd to you though?

Comment: There are many good reasons not to share the actual data. You could try to simulate data instead, which has the property you describe. Perhaps even in working out how to the simulation, you'll discover what's going on.